# How to test a label in Vue 3 Quasar component using forEach loop with Jest.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, quasar-framework

In my Vue Quasar component, I have a badge like this:

```
<q-badge
    :color="green"
    text-color="white"
    :label="`${value.toFixed(2)}%`"
/>
```

and script like this:

```
<script setup>
    const props = defineProps({
        value: Number
    })
</script>
```

I want to test my label for 3 different values

my test is like this:

```
let wrapper
const values_for_badge = [10, 50, 90]
const componentBadge = (props) =>{
    wrapper = mount(Badge, {
        props:{
            ...props
        }
    });
};

describe('Badge with injected values', () =>{
    values_for_badge.forEach(value => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            componentBadge({value:value})
        });
        
        it(`The right text label for value ${value}`, () => {
            expect(wrapper.text()).toBe(`${value.toFixed(2)}%`)
        }
    })
})
```

When I run it I have 3 tests. One is green but 2 are red because the expected result is different from what I have for example I expect 10.00% or 50.00% but I have always 90.00% so the value in the test is always the last one in array values_for_badge, but in the description of the test I have the right value from loop forEach.
The component in my app works well and has the correct labels.

How to modify the test for this component?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to resolve this problem like this:

```
describe('Badge with injected values', () =>{
    values_for_badge.forEach(value => {
       
        it(`The right text label for value ${value}`, () => {
            componentBadge({value:value});
            expect(wrapper.text()).toBe(`${value.toFixed(2)}%`);
        }
    })
})
```

Normally I have many more tests in this suite so I would like to put beforeEach in this case.